# SSRS Subscriptions - How to view ALL report recipients

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subscriptions

I've written an SSRS report to help me keep track of SSRS subscriptions.  I've repurposed a script that will use Reportserver.dbo.Subscriptions.LastStatus to view email recipients, however, it will only list the first 520 characters of LastStatus.  Because some of our distribution lists are quite large, some of the names that my script searches for are not being found (even though they are part of the distribution).  Below is the script that I am using:

```
SELECT Reportname = c.Name 
  ,FileLocation = c.Path
  ,SubscriptionDesc=su.Description 
  ,Subscriptiontype=su.EventType 
  ,su.LastStatus 
  ,su.LastRunTime 
  ,Schedulename=sch.Name 
  ,ScheduleType = sch.EventType 
  ,ScheduleFrequency = 
   CASE sch.RecurrenceType 
   WHEN 1 THEN 'Once' 
   WHEN 2 THEN 'Hourly' 
   WHEN 4 THEN 'Daily/Weekly' 
   WHEN 5 THEN 'Monthly' 
   END 
  ,su.Parameters 
  FROM Reportserver.dbo.Subscriptions su 
  JOIN Reportserver.dbo.Catalog c 
    ON su.Report_OID = c.ItemID 
  JOIN Reportserver.dbo.ReportSchedule rsc 
    ON rsc.ReportID = c.ItemID 
   AND rsc.SubscriptionID = su.SubscriptionID 
  JOIN Reportserver.dbo.Schedule Sch 
    ON rsc.ScheduleID = sch.ScheduleID 
WHERE  LastStatus like @Email
ORDER BY LastRunTime DESC
```

Any code that I have found online uses the LastStatus column to display this data.  If anyone has any suggestions as to a more complete way for me to list all of the members of the report distribution list, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Below is SQL to query for the full text of the subscription parameters. I think this will work with extremely long address lists, but I don't have a test server with long address lists available right now.

If using this in production, I'd probably throw in a couple of `WITH ( NOLOCK )`'s and wouldn't expect support from MS on problems.

```
   ;
   WITH subscriptionXmL
          AS (
               SELECT
                SubscriptionID ,
                OwnerID ,
                Report_OID ,
                Locale ,
                InactiveFlags ,
                ExtensionSettings ,
                CONVERT(XML, ExtensionSettings) AS ExtensionSettingsXML ,
                ModifiedByID ,
                ModifiedDate ,
                Description ,
                LastStatus ,
                EventType ,
                MatchData ,
                LastRunTime ,
                Parameters ,
                DeliveryExtension ,
                Version
               FROM
                ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions
             ),
                 -- Get the settings as pairs
        SettingsCTE
          AS (
               SELECT
                SubscriptionID ,
                ExtensionSettings ,
    -- include other fields if you need them.
                ISNULL(Settings.value('(./*:Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(1024)'),
                       'Value') AS SettingName ,
                Settings.value('(./*:Value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS SettingValue
               FROM
                subscriptionXmL
                CROSS APPLY subscriptionXmL.ExtensionSettingsXML.nodes('//*:ParameterValue') Queries ( Settings )
             )
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        SettingsCTE
    WHERE
        settingName IN ( 'TO', 'CC', 'BCC' )
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!  The ability to search both the TO and CC is perfect, because I was hoping to fix that portion of the report next.  Very nice script!  Thank you for your help Jamie

Comment: This is completely awesome.  How do I update an e-mail address en masse, though? The use case is a former employee put their company email address in the report.

Answer (score 6):

I also found this query from [SQL Server MSDN Social](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/002475a9-0556-4722-af38-d17ab6972cbe/details-of-reports-scheduled-on-ssrs-report-name-userdetails-frequency-etc?forum=sqlreportingservices);
Original Query Author MSDN Profile:  [Sandip Shinde](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/sandip%20shinde/)

```
SELECT
c.Name AS ReportName,
'Next Run Date' = CASE next_run_date
WHEN 0 THEN null
ELSE
substring(convert(varchar(15),next_run_date),1,4) + '/' +
substring(convert(varchar(15),next_run_date),5,2) + '/' +
substring(convert(varchar(15),next_run_date),7,2)
END,
'Next Run Time' = isnull(CASE len(next_run_time)
WHEN 3 THEN cast('00:0'
+ Left(right(next_run_time,3),1)
+':' + right(next_run_time,2) as char (8))
WHEN 4 THEN cast('00:'
+ Left(right(next_run_time,4),2)
+':' + right(next_run_time,2) as char (8))
WHEN 5 THEN cast('0' + Left(right(next_run_time,5),1)
+':' + Left(right(next_run_time,4),2)
+':' + right(next_run_time,2) as char (8))
WHEN 6 THEN cast(Left(right(next_run_time,6),2)
+':' + Left(right(next_run_time,4),2)
+':' + right(next_run_time,2) as char (8))
END,'NA'),
Convert(XML,[ExtensionSettings]).value('(//ParameterValue/Value[../Name="TO"])[1]','nvarchar(50)') as [To]
,Convert(XML,[ExtensionSettings]).value('(//ParameterValue/Value[../Name="CC"])[1]','nvarchar(50)') as [CC]
,Convert(XML,[ExtensionSettings]).value('(//ParameterValue/Value[../Name="RenderFormat"])[1]','nvarchar(50)') as [Render Format]
,Convert(XML,[ExtensionSettings]).value('(//ParameterValue/Value[../Name="Subject"])[1]','nvarchar(50)') as [Subject]
---Example report parameters: StartDateMacro, EndDateMacro &amp; Currency.
,Convert(XML,[Parameters]).value('(//ParameterValue/Value[../Name="StartDateMacro"])[1]','nvarchar(50)') as [Start Date]
,Convert(XML,[Parameters]).value('(//ParameterValue/Value[../Name="EndDateMacro"])[1]','nvarchar(50)') as [End Date]
,Convert(XML,[Parameters]).value('(//ParameterValue/Value[../Name="Currency"])[1]','nvarchar(50)') as [Currency]
,[LastStatus]
,[EventType]
,[LastRunTime]
,[DeliveryExtension]
,[Version]
FROM 
 dbo.[Catalog] c
INNER JOIN dbo.[Subscriptions] S ON c.ItemID = S.Report_OID
INNER JOIN dbo.ReportSchedule R ON S.SubscriptionID = R.SubscriptionID
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs J ON Convert(nvarchar(128),R.ScheduleID) = J.name
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules JS ON J.job_id = JS.job_id
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/manage-subscription-owners-and-run-subscription-powershell?view=sql-server-ver16), you can also use this powershell command:

```
$webSRV = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://myservername/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx" -Namespace SSRS.ReportingService2010 -UseDefaultCredential;  
$mySubsList = $webSRV.ListSubscriptions("/");  
$mySubsList | select *
```